# Is it possible to add custom buttons to notifications in Tizen wearable using Tizen Web API?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I've been developing a Tizen web application for wearable devices that need to show notifications to users from time to time. using Notification API (Web App on Tizen OS version 4.0) it seems impossible to add custom buttons to a notification.

Do you have any suggestions/workarounds?

P.S. it seems possible to do so with Native API (C language), but I need to get it done in Web App API (Javascript) if possible.

Answer (score 2):

As far I know, adding custom buttons to notification is not possible using Tizen Web API.

As a workaround I can advise you development of [hybrid application](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/packaging-hybrid-application) which uses native API to [create your customized notification with buttons](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/notification/notifications/#creating-an-active-notification-with-text-input) and develop other functionalities in Web application.